# Why react-native app restarts when hot reloads (changes saved in hot reloading mode)?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on react-native (0.57) app on IOS platform. When I save code changes in the code editor (hot reloading enabled), IOS app restarts whereas in Android it's working fine. In Android, it only updates that page and don't restarts. It is normal behaviour for IOS or I may be doing something wrong?

I have tested this on real physical devices. IOS (iphone-5s), Android (MI 3s prime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely normal for an iOS app to restart on updation.

> **Android has instant app support which enable it to just reload the changes without quitting the app, whereas the iOS doesn't have any
>   such options available yet, it has to reload the entire app**

So don't bother about it and enjoy coding.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Atleast now I can be confident thats it is happening with all ;D

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help you.